# wordpress and IONCUBE issue

Tags: php, wordpress, ioncube

i am using a premium theme in WordPress 4.0. but problem is when i tried to change function.php file, it return error

```
"encoded function.php file is corrupted."
```

all data in function.php file is encoded. i am not able to change it. is there any other way to add some functions in my theme?

Comment: Contact the theme author were you purchased the theme from. They **have** to help you, you paid for the theme. Otherwise, demand a refund

Answer (score 1):

Did you really expect anything else? Files are protected with digital signatures and if you change the contents it will corrupt them. This is by design as a provider may wish to add copyright messages and not want them taken out. If you desire more functionality in purchased code, you should contact the provider to request this, even if you are able also to add it yourself. The feedback loop from customers back to software developers is essential for products to move forwards, and it hurts product development when it is bypassed by people making their own changes that more than likely will not get contributed back to the product developers. To avoid corrupting the files, add functionality in files outside of the protected component, and also raise an issue with the developers if you feel that they have protected too much of the software so as to not make it flexible enough. 
Disclosure: I am associated with ionCube.

Answer (score 0):

use child theme concept, where you can easily add functions

Comment: i have tried child theme concept but not working.. show error from parent function file

Comment: may be you while uploading images from the wordpress admin panel, your hosting server encoding the theme and file is being corrupted. try direct ftp uploading for theme

Comment: all find solution to overwrite function file in my case...created small plugin for MYfunction_Action() and it works like charm....